# Creating Service Fabric Api service only allows ASP .NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

When creating a new Service Fabric service I am looking to create the API service targeting `ASP.NET Core 3.1`. The only option I have available however is `ASP.NET Core 2.1`. I am using visual studio 2017 (15.9.18).

How do I add or enable ASP .NET Core 3.1, is this only available in Visual Studio 2019?

[image: Creating-Api-Only-AspNetCore2.1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 isn't supported for building dotnet core 3.x applications.

From the announcement post:

> Visual Studio 2019 will be the release to support building .NET Core 3
>   applications

and

> It is currently possible to open .NET Core 3.0 projects in Visual
>   Studio 2017 15.9, however, it is not a supported scenario

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-preview-1-and-open-sourcing-windows-desktop-frameworks/

There is some information about enabling previews to get it working but you run into other issues with MSBuild versions.